# Add a new field to the existing vendor bundle entity with yml configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to add a many-to-one association to an existing entity in vendor bundle.

This is my entity in vendor bundle:-

```
class Post
{
    private $id;

    private $title;

    private $accroche;

    private $article;

    private $categories;

    private $comments;

    private $created;

    private $updated;

    private $publied;
}
```

And, this is the orm mapping file for Post entity in vendor bundle:-

```
Mv\BlogBundle\Entity\AdminBlog\Post:
  type:                 entity
  table:                null
  repositoryClass:      Mv\BlogBundle\Entity\AdminBlog\PostRepository
  id:
    id:
      type:             integer
      generator:
        strategy:       AUTO

  fields:
    title:
      type:             string
      length:           150
    accroche:
      type:             text
    article:
      type:             text
    created:
      type:             datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: create
    updated:
      type:             datetime
      gedmo:
        timestampable:
          on: update
    publied:
      type:             datetime

  manyToMany:
    categories:
      targetEntity:   Mv\BlogBundle\Entity\AdminBlog\Category
      inversedBy:     posts
      joinTable:
        name:         post_category
        joinColumns:
          post_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete:             CASCADE
        inverseJoinColumns:
          category_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete:             RESTRICT

  oneToMany:
    comments:
      targetEntity:   Mv\BlogBundle\Entity\AdminBlog\Comment
      mappedBy:       post
```

I created a child bundle of my vendor bundle. I researched on mappedSuperclass and tried other inheritance methods. But none of them worked for just adding an association to 'Post' entity.

I just want to have something like the following (tried adding it in orm mapping file but not working):-

```
manyToOne:
  user:
    targetEntity:   TP\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\User
    joinColumns:
        user_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
```

Answer (score 0):

As solution, I can suggest [SonataEasyExtendsBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/index.html). As [docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/why.html#lets-start-to-mix-these-points-together) says, one of problems which it solves is:

> If a developer wants to add a new property into a VB entity, the
>   developer needs to create a new child entity with a custom mapping.

But it has some [requirements](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/why.html#how-to-make-your-bundle-easy-extendable) for Vendor Bundle. You can read the short [explanation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/reference/why.html) and decide, whether it is solution for you.